# How to create an asset tracking/verification system

Tags: nft, signature

New to this (currently a Kotlin dev) so looking for some starting points to research how to create a system to do the following:

1. Handle a user creating an asset with some data (e.g. a timesheet with days/hours) as an NFT, Token ...?
2. Handle displaying the NFT data to someone (e.g. a manager) and have them 'sign' it as a means of approval
3. Handle displaying the NFT data to someone else (e.g. the finance department) and they will be able to see it's been approved by the manager in 2)